# WordPress popup without plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<div>
<?php do_action( 'opalestate_member_login_form' ); ?>
 <a href="#opalestate-user-form-popup" class="opalestate-need-login button btn btn-primary btn-3d">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'opalestate-pro' ) ?>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This code shows up a popup on button click.
But i need help to show auto popup on page. without clicking any button.(WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to run button click event when the page loaded.
Add this code into your page that popup is there.

```js
$(function(){
$('.opalestate-need-login').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there any other way, without using the button.

Comment: Your welcome. It depends on your popup source. You should check your popup view process and call to view that with jquery or css. In generally the popup display is false. So you can change that to true.